# Webcomponent Custom Element pass function onClick

Tags: javascript, react-component

I want to pass a function to Custom Element using ReactJS

ReactJS Component

```
import React from 'react';
import './SampleComponent';

export  class Button extends React.Component {

  handleClick = (event) => {
    console.log(event)
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <div>
        <sample-component onclick="handleClick"></sample-component>
      </div>
    )
  }
};
```

Custom Element

```
class SampleComponent extends HTMLElement {
  static get observedAttributes() {

  }

  // custom methods
  render() {
    this.innerHTML = `Custom Element`;
  }

  // lifecycle hooks
  connectedCallback() {
    this.render();
  }

}

window.customElements.define('sample-component', SampleComponent);
```

As I understand, when I pass onclick function `handleClick` JS will search for it in Custom Element implementation (that's why I get an error in console). So how to pass a function? I tried `"this.handle"` but it also didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to the react [Documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html) you html should look like this

```
<sample-component onClick={handleClick}></sample-component>
```